# What is the "Obscuration Factor (OBF)"?

Tags: optics, reflection, laser

In a paper I am reading for my master thesis I came across this "obscuration factor (OBF)". The authors indicate that it is a measurement of the average intensity of reflection. They do not give a formula or any more information about it.

I have searched for a mathematical expression for it, but have not been able to find any. I only find information about alcoholic beverages and other non-optic related areas.

Is anyone familiar with it?

Some extra info, cells are being beamed with a laser, and it is the intensity of the back-reflectance what is being measured and subjected to the OBF

Comment: Google `"obscuration factor" -alcohol -alcoholic`. Lots of optics links.